# blank cd's are not correctly id'd

Tags: cd, burning

I have been trying to burn a cd using memorex cd-r cd's. I've tried k3b and braserio with no luck. k3b reports that it "didn't like" the media. when I pull up the disk information, it tells me that the media has 2.0 kb of space when it's a blank 700mb disk and the drive says it's "read only". Media and drive work properly in Windows. HELP!

currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

cd info:

[image]

****Did the following in terminal****
me@ABC:~$ wodim dev=help
Supported SCSI transports for this platform:

Transport name:     sg
Transport descr.:   Generic transport independent SCSI
Transp. layer ind.: 
Target specifier:   bus,target,lun
Target example:     1,2,0
SCSI Bus scanning:  supported
Open via UNIX device:   not supported

Transport name:     ATA
Transport descr.:   ATA Packet specific SCSI transport
Transp. layer ind.: ATAPI:
Target specifier:   bus,target,lun
Target example:     ATAPI:1,2,0
SCSI Bus scanning:  supported
Open via UNIX device:   not supported

Transport name:     ATA
Transport descr.:   ATA Packet specific SCSI transport using sg interface
Transp. layer ind.: ATA:
Target specifier:   bus,target,lun
Target example:     1,2,0
SCSI Bus scanning:  supported
Open via UNIX device:   not supported

Transport name:     RSCSI
Transport descr.:   Remote SCSI
Transp. layer ind.: REMOTE: 
Target specifier:   rscsi@host:bus,target,lun
Target example:     REMOTE:rscsi@host:1,2,0
SCSI Bus scanning:  supported
Open via UNIX device:   not supported

would the "Open via UNIX device:    not supported" be the problem and, if so, can this be fixed?

Comment: check which back-end is used, [cdrkit](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html) or [cdrtools](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools), cdrtools is recommended

Answer (score 0):

The shown screenshot is somewhat misleading by its statement "Size 2.0 KB"
which should rather be "Size 0". Elsewise the CD-R seems to be correctly
recognized as unwritten (aka "blank").

The run of wodim only produces a help text about outdated device classes.
Use /dev/sr0 as address and ignore the "not supported" (which is not true
for "sg" anyways).

If you want to go on with the command line, you'd need to tell what kind of
CD you strive for: CD-DA for music playing, CD-ROM for data storage. Further
you'd need to tell by which file name paths the input files are accessible
on your hard disk.

If you rather prefer to stay with K3b or Brasero, then you need to tell
which error messages they emit. "K3b didn't like" does not contain enough
information for guessing what might be wrong.

---

I tested what wodim has to say about an empty medium:

```
wodim dev=/dev/sr0 -toc
```

It reported:

```
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'ASUS    '
Identification : 'BW-16D1HT       '
Revision       : '1.01'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), read toc scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  43 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x24 Qual 0x00 (invalid field in cdb) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
resid: 4
cmd finished after 0.002s timeout 40s
wodim: Cannot read TOC header
wodim: Cannot read TOC/PMA
```

This is not very re-assuring because an inappropiate SCSI transaction
is reported and no info about the medium status is reported.

Better results yields

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc
```

which reports for me

```
Drive current: -outdev '/dev/sr0'
Media current: CD-R
Media status : is blank
Media summary: 0 sessions, 0 data blocks, 0 data,  703m free
Drive current: -outdev '/dev/sr0'
Drive type   : vendor 'ASUS' product 'BW-16D1HT' revision '1.01'
Drive id     : 'K9CF92A5012 '
Media current: CD-R
Media product: 97m34s23f/79m59s73f , Mitsubishi Chemical Corporation
Media status : is blank
Media blocks : 0 readable , 359846 writable , 359846 overall
Media summary: 0 sessions, 0 data blocks, 0 data,  703m free
```

We see that the medium is a CD-R, is blank, offers room for 703 MiB
(= 737 MB) of data, and was actually made by Mitsubishi (aka "Verbatim").